# How to upload large files from Android without OutOfMemory Error?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I need upload at least 16 Mb files from Android to my server, but it turns when the files exced 9 Mb the next error ->

```
10-17 05:21:57.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2185): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-17 05:21:57.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2185):     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
10-17 05:21:57.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2185):     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
10-17 05:21:57.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2185):     at libcore.net.http.RetryableOutputStream.write(RetryableOutputStream.java:61)
10-17 05:21:57.600: E/AndroidRuntime(2185):     at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
```

This is part of the code I can post entire code if its neccesary

```
      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
```

Thanks

David

Comment: Can you *skip* the ByteArrayOutputStream? That's the culprit. Perhaps is there a "retry" option that can be disabled?

Comment: Hi User, I'm newbie in Java, and really I don't know how to skip that process. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can enable the streaming mode to avoid copying the uploaded file to phone's memory completely before sending it.

```
        // set the request mode as POST
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // disable using cache.
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

        // enable Output/Input.
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        // enable the streaming mode.
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(128 * 1024);
```